Operating system wasn't found and PC is not booting. What should I do?
I have a 1TB HDD in my PC and I partitioned (divided) it into (D) disk. I accidentally set it as active partition.
Now my PC is not booting it showing that:

"Operating System Wasn't Found"

What should I do?

Have you tried making the old partition active/bootable?
